# Codeigniter with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I want to save with Stored Procedure. Please check my script first

```
`USE [Payroll]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[ResignSave]    
(    
 @ResignCode varchar(50),    
 @Nip Varchar(50),
 @Keterangan Varchar(50),
 @ResignDate Varchar(50),
 @CreatedBy varchar(50),
 @CreatedDate date,
 @msg varchar(25) = NULL

)    
AS 
BEGIN
Begin Try


set @ResignCode = (select case 
    when right(max(ResignCode),7) is null then 'RC0000001' 
        else ('RC' + RIGHT('0000000' + cast(right(max(ResignCode),7) + 1 as nvarchar),7)) 
 end ResignCode from Resign)        

    INSERT INTO Resign(ResignCode,Nip, Keterangan, ResignDate, CreatedBy,CreatedDate)
            VALUES(@ResignCode,@Nip,@Keterangan, @ResignDate,@CreatedBy,GETDATE())  
end try

Begin Catch           
  Select ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage               
 End Catch                                  
End   
`
```

My Stored Procedure working fine. My question is, is there anyway to checking the input if it's exists in my table then set it to my `@msg`.

Comment: what do you mean of "input" ? (is there anyway to checking the input if it's exists )

Comment: the input are from my website.

Comment: so you are calling this procedure in your web page to save data entry. and you want to see if the record already exists. Right?

Comment: and what is your primary key? or unique key?

Comment: Yep . That's true. I want to check if Nip, Keterangan & ResignDate already inserted. because third of them cannot be inserted twice with same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for below code.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[ResignSave]    
(    
 @ResignCode varchar(50),    
 @Nip Varchar(50),
 @Keterangan Varchar(50),
 @ResignDate Varchar(50),
 @CreatedBy varchar(50),
 @CreatedDate date,
 @msg varchar(25) = NULL

)    
AS 
BEGIN
  Begin Try

    if exists (select * from Resign where ResignCode = @ResignCode and Nip = @Nip and ResignDate = @ResignDate) then
    BEGIN
        set @msg = 'Record already exists'
        select @msg AS ProcResult
    END

    set @ResignCode = (select case 
        when right(max(ResignCode),7) is null then 'RC0000001' 
        else ('RC' + RIGHT('0000000' + cast(right(max(ResignCode),7) + 1 as nvarchar),7)) 
    end ResignCode from Resign)        

    INSERT INTO Resign(ResignCode,Nip, Keterangan, ResignDate, CreatedBy,CreatedDate)
            VALUES(@ResignCode,@Nip,@Keterangan, @ResignDate,@CreatedBy,GETDATE())  

    SELECT 'Insert Successful' AS ProcResult
  end try

  Begin Catch           
    Select 'Insert Failed:' + cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar) + ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ProcResult
  End Catch                                  
End
```

If this is what you are looking for, you don't need the @msg parameter. juts execute the procedure and get the returned result set

Comment: Now i'm trying to send @msg to my php .

Comment: aw. i stuck there. Is it possible if i do this `select @msg;`

Comment: You can do that or you can use output parameter. I edit my answer. take a look